# How to ajaxify webform submit in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, ajax, webforms

I have tried to alter the webform rendering using `hook_form_alter()` and `hook_node_view()` in a custom module so I could add '#ajax' somewhere.

Has anybody already had some experience working with webform and ajax on D6 or D7 ?
I guess the logic would be the same for D6 and D7 then just the implementation changes.

Comment: D6 and D7 have very different Ajax frameworks.

Comment: Yes they do, but its not an issue. The real issue i'm having is that i can't find a hook to alter the Webform form and add an ajax event through Drupal form API.

Comment: Do you have a specific question regarding Ajax? This sounds conversational.  Also, just for reference: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--ajax.inc/group/ajax/7

Comment: I don't really like posting answers just with links to "how to" blog posts without any explanation of my own so I'll just add this as a comment: http://envisioninteractive.com/drupal/add-ajax-to-a-webform-in-drupal-7/ -- if this ends up working, we can consider adding it as an answer perhaps. It seems like this is what you might need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Ajax Module](http://drupal.org/project/ajax) works for me in Drupal 6.

For Drupal 7:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      // see if webform_client_form_ is in the form_id
      if(strstr($form_id, 'webform_client_form_')) {
        // get the nid so we can use it in the wrapper value
        $nid = $form['#node']->nid;
        // add the ajax properties to the submit button
        $form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
          'callback' => 'mymodule_webform_js_submit',
          'wrapper' => 'webform-client-form-' . $nid,
          'method' => 'replace',
          'effect' => 'fade',
        );
      }
    }

function mymodule_webform_js_submit($form, $form_state) {
      // define the $sid variable (submission id from webform)
      $sid = $form_state['values']['details']['sid'];
      // if we have a sid then we know the form was properly submitted, otherwise, we'll just return the existing $form array
      if ($sid) {
        // first we have to load up the webform node object
        $node = node_load($form_state['values']['details']['nid']);
        // create an array up with the confirmation message, retreived from the webform node
        $confirmation = array(
          '#type' => 'markup',
          '#markup' => check_markup($node->webform['confirmation'], $node->webform['confirmation_format'], '', TRUE),
        );
        // return the confirmation message
        return $confirmation;
      }
      else {
        // return the form
        return $form;
      }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is this code supposed to do? I added it to my theme (after changing the hook's names to match my theme), but I don't notice any impact.

Comment: It goes into a custom module within your theme.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiseast way if you are looking to ajaxify just a particular form will be to add the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). Its pretty straight forward.

Add the below code to you page preprocess function in template.php file.

1. **First add the jquery plugin with below code.**

   drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'your_theme') . "/js/jquery.form.js");
2. **Then Add the below code, replace `#your_form_ID` with form id of yours**

   drupal_add_js('

   ```
               (function($){ 
   $(document).ready(function() { 

               $("#your_form_ID").ajaxForm(function() { 
                   alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
               }); 
   });     }(jQuery));;

          ', 'inline');
   ```

That's all you are done. Maybe you want to consider loading the scripts only the pages you need.

Comment: I have been considering it. Now I am thinking of making it an module with a config page so all can benefit. Does anything like that exist?

Answer (score -1):

See if the [Ajax module](http://drupal.org/project/ajax) can help you with that.  See the [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/349961) as well

Comment: He's asking for Drupal 7, that module is not yet available for D7.

Comment: To be fair, although the question is tagged as 7, it does explicitly ask if anyone had experience with ajax in D6 or D7.